# Why do we greatly honor the Davidic line of kings?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, malchut-royalty, kavod

I have trouble understanding why we greatly honor the Davidic line of kings, why we pray for the restoration of the dynasty.  Taking as examples the last six major kings of the Davidic line, they either encouraged idolatry or used poor judgment that resulted in disastrous consequences.

ChIizkiyyahu (Hezekiah) was righteous, but used poor judgment in rebelling against the Assyrian Empire (Sennacherib). It cost 300 talents of silver and 30 talents of gold.(2Kings 18:16)

Manasseh re-instituted pagan worship in the Temple.(Jeremiah 15:4)

Amon continued his father’s practice of idolatry.(2Kings 21:19-22)

Yoshiyahu (Josiah) was righteous, but used poor judgment in rebelling against the Egyptian Empire and going into battle against them.(2 Chronicles 35:20-24)

Yehoyakim (Jehoiakim) kept switching alliances and used poor judgment in burning the Book of Jeremiah.(Jeremiah 36:1-32)

Tsidkiyyahu (Zedekiah) did not listen to Jeremiah and rebelled against the Babylonians, which led to the utter destruction of Jerusalem and the Temple.

Other than messianic longings, why do we give them so much honor?

Comment: "Other than messianic longings" why can't that be the reason?

Comment: Don't forget Asa, Jehoshaphat, Jehoash, Amaziah, Uzziah, and Jotham, who had (mostly), outstanding reigns. I think it is a mistake hold people to a standard of perfection. God certainly does not. Look no farther than the patriarchs.

Comment: @Yishai Because I don't see why that's a reason to give them honor? AFAIK we don't honor them ispo facto. We honor their position.

Comment: What do you mean by "give so much honor"?

Comment: @DoubleAA, perhaps I misunderstand the question, but I thought it was asking about the position (the "Davidic line").

Comment: Mick, [edit]ing in where you see we greatly honor these kings would realty improve your question (as others have implied, above). As it stands, this is like asking why we greatly honor the redwood. (We don't.)